# QXmlStreamWriter in Qt 5.15.1

Tags: xml, linux, qt, svg

I'm trying to replace attributes in SVG file using QXmlStreamReader & QXmlStreamWriter.

Part1:

```
QXmlStreamReader xml(&file);
QXmlStreamWriter wxml(&m_svgImage);
while (!xml.atEnd() && !xml.hasError()) {
    xml.readNext();
    wxml.writeCurrentToken(xml);
}
```

Part2:

```
QXmlStreamReader xml(m_svgImage);
QByteArray updatedImage;
QXmlStreamWriter wxml(&updatedImage);
while (!xml.atEnd() && !xml.hasError()) {
    QXmlStreamReader::TokenType token = xml.readNext();
    wxml.writeCurrentToken(xml);
}
```

after Part1 svg file is showed well, but after Part2 in file appears changes:

```
<n1:svg xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" width="8.4666mm" ...
```

vs

```
<n1:svg xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" width="8.4666mm" height="8.4666mm" ...
```

my Qt5.15.1 C++ app does'nt wont to display it on Linux Mint 20 Xfce 64-bit, but on Qt 5.5 w Astralinux it works well. Some time ago before update of Qt or Mint/Ubuntu it was fine too.
How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: Do i can fix something?

Comment: The button says: `Ask Question`. You didn't ask one.

Comment: It's my first question, what do i need to do?

Comment: It does not show enough information to help finding a solution. Please prepare a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).